# Passing a function with parameters to a child component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, events, callback, blazor

I'm writing blazor component wrappers for some of my favorite Javascript plugins using Javascript interop.

My parent component has this function:

```
async Task<IEnumerable<DpEvent>> GetEvents(DateRange dateRange)
{
    return await EventManager.GetEvents().Where(e => e.StartDate >= dateRange.StartDate).Where(e => e.EndDate <= dateRange.EndDate).ToListAsync();
}
```

and my childcomponent has this parameter:

```
[Parameter] public Func<DateRange, Task<IEnumerable<DpEvent>>> GetEvents { get; set; }
```

What must I do to pass my GetEvents Method to my child component like so:

```
<ChildComponent GetEvents="GetEvents"></ChildComponent>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by creating a custom delegate for my callback.

Function I wanted to pass to child component:

```
async Task<IEnumerable<DpEvent>> GetEvents(DateRange dateRange)
{
    return await EventManager.GetEvents().Where(e => e.StartDate >= dateRange.StartDate).Where(e => e.EndDate <= dateRange.EndDate).ToListAsync();
}
```

Definition and Declaration of my delegates:

```
public delegate Task<IEnumerable<DpEvent>> GetEventsDelegate(DateRange dateRange);
public GetEventsDelegate GetEventsCallBack;
```

Assigning my delegates to my function:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    GetEventsCallBack = GetEvents;
}
```

Passing my delegate to my child component:

```
<ChildComponent GetEvents="GetEventsCallBack"></ChildComponent>
```

My Parameter on my Child Component:

```
[Parameter] public Func<DateRange, Task<IEnumerable<DpEvent>>> GetEvents { get; set; }
```

And finally, my child component can use the delegate:

```
IEnumerable<DpEvent> dpEvents = await GetEvents.Invoke(dateRange);
```